# Angular: How can I call a controller function from an HTML view using ng-if or another Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

My question is; how can I call a controller function from my view when a condition is met/equates to true, using `ng-if` or perhaps some other Angular directive?

**Something like this:**

```
<div ng-if="dataHasBeenLoaded == 'true'" ng-init="configureWordCloudGraph()"></div>
```

**This is what I would like to achieve:**

When my data has loaded and was retrieved via my API call, I would like to set a `$scope` variable (`$scope.dataHasBeenLoaded = true`;) to true. And when this `$scope` variable === true, it is evaluated in my DOM, and then calls a function `configureWordCloudGraph()` in my controller:

```
$scope.configureWordCloudGraph = function () {

    if ($scope.dataHasBeenLoaded) {
        var data = $scope.wordCloudData;
        $scope.twitterProfileWords = WordCloud.setUpTags(data.words);
    }

}
```

This is my view:

```
<div ng-controller="TwitterWordCloudController">
    <div id="word">
        <og-data-box heading="Most used words on Twitter" link="" uid="socialMentionsMeta" description="">
            <div class="dataStatus" ng-show="!dataContent">{{dataStatus}}<og-loading-indicator></og-loading-indicator></div>
            <div class="dataContent" ng-show="dataContent" ng-mouseover="showGraphTrainingInfo()">
                <og-word-cloud words="twitterProfileWords"></og-word-cloud>
                <div ng-if="dataHasBeenLoaded == 'true'" ng-init="configureWordCloudGraph()"></div>
            </div>
        </og-data-box>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why won't you invoke the configureWordCloudGraph function directly in the controller after you load the data?

Comment: @PawełKozikowski Beat me to it.

Comment: The way you calling controller is correct. Whats the error are you getting ?

Comment: Good and obvious question! i actually do. HOWEVER, for some reason, the SVG WordCloud does not display all the time. It seems it DOES actually generate the WordCloud, but it is like it is hidden. I have to resize the page before it refreshes and displays. I am testing to see if I can re-call the function, and what effect it will have.

Comment: @selvassn I am not getting an error, but it does not hit my break-point. I thought I might have made a mistake in my code or something.

Comment: Back to the drawing board :)

Comment: Please check how it is actually hidden: if it's done by angular or something else. Also check the value of 'dataContent' - that's the variable responsible for showing the cloud. Maybe you should also invoke the showGraphTrainingInfo after you load the data?

Comment: @Paweł Kozikowski If I look at my `$scope`, my `dataModel dataContent = true`, `dataStatus = " "`. However the `dataStatus` does not seem to make a difference to the WordCloud not displaying, as the `dataStatus` remains `" "` even when the WordCloud is displaying. Can you perhaps give me more info regarding `showGraphTrainingInfo` and how to implement it? Thank you!

Comment: @onmyway I thought that you have this function already implemented, as you have this attribute: ng-mouseover="showGraphTrainingInfo()"

Comment: @Paweł Kozikowski Thank you. Copied the code from another view... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment from selvassn, the way to call an Angular controller from an HTML view is as follows:

**NOTE:** I'll break it down in 3 parts of code; Just the HTML method call, the controller method, the complete HTML code including the controller method call.

**Just the HTML Controller Method call code:**

```
<div ng-if="dataHasBeenLoaded == 'true'" ng-init="configureWordCloudGraph()"></div>
```

**Controller Method:**

```
$scope.configureWordCloudGraph = function () {

    if ($scope.dataHasBeenLoaded) {
        var data = $scope.wordCloudData;
        $scope.twitterProfileWords = WordCloud.setUpTags(data.words);
    }

}
```

**HTML view Controller Method call:**

```
<div ng-controller="TwitterWordCloudController">
    <div id="word">
        <og-data-box heading="Most used words on Twitter" link="" uid="socialMentionsMeta" description="">
            <div class="dataStatus" ng-show="!dataContent">{{dataStatus}}<og-loading-indicator></og-loading-indicator></div>
            <div class="dataContent" ng-show="dataContent" ng-mouseover="showGraphTrainingInfo()">
                <og-word-cloud words="twitterProfileWords"></og-word-cloud>
                <div ng-if="dataHasBeenLoaded == 'true'" ng-init="configureWordCloudGraph()"></div>
            </div>
        </og-data-box>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way can be to watch dataHasBeenLoaded and launch configureWordCloudGraph when true :

```
var deregister = $scope.$watch('dataHasBeenLoaded', function() {
    if($scope.dataHasBeenLoaded) {
         configureWordCloudGraph();
         deregister();
    }
})
```

Comment: Don't agree, watcher is launch when dataHasBeenLoaded is true, and the method deregister supress angular handle so watcher become 'inactive' and doesn't impact performance